# need to combine two arrays by matching

Tags: arrays

```
Array1 = [{ id:123, docName:test},{id:34, docName: renderTest}]

Array2 = [{ docName:test, url:abc.pdf, status:uploaded},{docName: renderTest, url:sfhh.pdf, status: failure}]
```

I need a array with matching docName and create array with object values together (need to combine two arrays by matching docName]

```
FinalArr = [{ id:123,docName:test, url:abc.pdf, status:uploaded},{id:34,docName: renderTest, url:sfhh.pdf, status: failure}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array#map` and `Array#find` coupled with some destructuring. This solution assumes, per your example, that `Array1` and `Array2` always have the same number of elements and each `docName` value - **please use "" for all your strings** - in each array has a corresponding value in the other.

```js
const Array1 = [{ id:123, docName:"test"},{id:34, docName: "renderTest"}],
      Array2 = [{ docName:"test", url:"abc.pdf", status:"uploaded"},{docName: "renderTest", url:"sfhh.pdf", status: "failure"}],
      
      FinalArr = Array1.map(
          ({docName, ...r1}) => 
          ({docName, ...r1, ...(Array2.find(({docName:dn}) => dn === docName) || {})})
      );
      
console.log( FinalArr );
```

**Alternatively, ....**
You can combine the two arrays, sort and group items with same `docName` together and then process the groups as before:

```js
const Array1 = [{ id:123, docName:"test"},{id:34, docName: "renderTest"}],
      Array2 = [{ docName:"test", url:"abc.pdf", status:"uploaded"},{docName: "renderTest", url:"sfhh.pdf", status: "failure"}],
      arr = [...Array1, ...Array2],
      
      FinalArr = arr.sort(
          ({docName:da}, {docName:db}) => 
          da.localeCompare(db)
      )
      .reduce(
          (acc,{docName,...r},i) => 
          arr[i+1] && arr[i+1].docName === docName ? [...acc,[arr[i],arr[i+1]]] : acc, []
      )
      .map(
          ([{docName, ...r1},{docName:db, ...r2}]) => 
          ({docName, ...r1, ...r2})
      );
      
console.log( FinalArr );
```